# LiipImagineBundle does not render image with filter

Tags: php, apache, symfony, liipimaginebundle

I followed all instructions to install LiipImagineBundle, with default configuration :

```
# app/config/config.yml
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
        default:
            web_path: ~

    filter_sets:
        cache: ~

        # the name of the "filter set"
        my_thumb:

            # adjust the image quality to 75%
            quality: 75

            # list of transformations to apply (the "filters")
            filters:

                # create a thumbnail: set size to 120x90 and use the "outbound" mode
                # to crop the image when the size ratio of the input differs
                thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }

                # create a 2px black border: center the thumbnail on a black background
                # 4px larger to create a 2px border around the final image
                background: { size: [124, 94], position: center, color: '#000000' }
```

The problem is that it does not render with the default filter :

```
<img src="{{ asset('/relative/path/to/image.jpg') | imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" />
```

If i put the image without the filter, it renders, so it is not a problem of image location.

With the filter, the link to the image that is generated is :

```
http://localhost/projets/test/web/app_dev.php/media/cache/resolve/my_thumb/projets/test/web/tabadoul-cover.jpg
```

And no image is created, no media folder (which normaly should be created for caching the image).

I really dont know where is the problem, but i suspect it is related with APACHE.

Any help would be appreciated

### EDIT 1

when I use the console command, the images are created :

```
php bin/console liip:imagine:cache:resolve app/img/tabadoul-cover.jpg
```

### EDIT 2

I tried to install the bundle on a new symfony project (3.4.36), and the problem persists when I use wampserver. BUT when i use the symfony server :

```
php bin/console server:run
```

the image is displayed !

So it is a problem of apache configuration ...

Comment: with LiipImagineBundle you do sometimes have to clear your browsers cache because of permanent redirects that the bundle creates. On the other hand if there are no images rendered you could try to inspect your requests and responses and find out if there are any errors.

Comment: when you use the command where is the image created by LiipImagine ?

Comment: there are 2 files created :

\web\media\cache\cache\app\img\tabadoul-cover.jpg
\web\media\cache\my_thumb\app\img\tabadoul-cover.jpg